Tmux copy-paste with mouse mode on while using the `less` command
Hopefully this is not already answered, given that there are 100s of question specifically about tmux copy-paste on mouse mode.
I am specifically trying to copy text using mouse selection while using the less command. The copy-paste works fine otherwise, but when viewing a file using the less command, it stops working.
Also note that the copy-paste works fine inside vim and other commands like more.
